# non-negative sequence with $a_{k+1} \leq a_k - b_k + c_k$, $\sum c_k <\infty$: showing $a_k$ have limit and $b$ goes to zero.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $\{a_k\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}}, \{b_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}, $ and $\{c_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be sequences of non-negative real numbers satisfying the inequality,

\begin{align}
a_{k+1} \leq a_k - b_k + c_k
\end{align}
for $k=0,1,2,\cdots$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k < \infty$.

I want to show that $b_k \rightarrow 0$ and $\{a_k\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ has a limit as $k \rightarrow \infty$.

---

Naively due to $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k < \infty$, we know $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} c_k =0$.

So taking $k \rightarrow \infty$, one have
\begin{align}
a_{\infty+1} \leq a_{\infty} - b_{\infty} + c_{\infty}
\end{align}
and since $c_{\infty} =0$ and if limit of $a_k$ exists this gurantees that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} b_k =0$.  But we do not have any information of $a_k$ except that inequality.

---

How one can prove the above theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n <m$. Then $\sum\limits_{k=n}^{m} (a_{k+1}-a_k) \leq \sum\limits_{k=n}^{m} c_k \to 0$ as $m >n \to \infty$. The left side is a telescopic sum and you get $a_{m+1}-a_n \leq \sum\limits_{k=n}^{m} c_k$. Clearly, this implies that $(a_n)$ is bounded. Suppose $a$ and $b$ are two limit points of $(a_n)$.  Then we get $a-b \leq 0$ and $b-a \leq 0$ by choosing $n$ and $m$ appropriately. [I will leave the details to you]. It follows that $(a_n)$ is convergent. Now $b_k \leq c_k -(a_{k+1}-a_k) \to 0$.

Comment: One can even conclude from $a_{m+1} + \sum_{k=0}^m b_k \le a_0 + \sum_{k=0}^m c_k$ that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k$ converges.

Comment: So a “one-sided Cauchy condition” $a_m - a_n < \epsilon$ for $m > n \ge N(\epsilon)$ implies convergence for a *bounded* sequence of real numbers. Do you happen to know if that is a known criterion? I never noticed it before.

Comment: ... I just found it: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2919323/42969.

Comment: You can always take $a_{m+1}$ close to $a$ and $a_n$ close to $B$ as well as the other way around still maintaining the condition $m>n$. So I think there is not much to this. @MartinR